# Weights Matrix Final Fully Connected Layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

My question is, I think, too simple, but it's giving me headaches. I think I'm missing either something conceptually in Neural Networks or Tensorflow is returning some wrong layer.

I have a network in which last layer outputs 4800 units. The penultimate layer has 2000 units. I expect my weight matrix for last layer to have the shape (4800, 2000) but when I print out the shape in Tensorflow I see (2000, 4800). Please can someone confirm which shape of weight matrix the last layer should have? Depending on the answer, I can further debug the issue. Thanks.

Comment: By convention the vectors are row-vectors and not column vectors.

Comment: Please can you expand on your answer a little?

Comment: So you go from 2000 units in the penultimate layer to 4800 units in the output layer is that right? In this case the shape of the weights would be (2000, 4800)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, a neural network layer is often written like `y = W*x` where * is matrix multiplication, `x` is an input vector and `y` an output vector. If `x` has 2000 units and y 4800, then indeed `W` should have size `(4800, 2000)`, i.e. 4800 rows and 2000 columns.

However, in implementations we usually work on a *batch* of inputs `X`. Say `X` is `(b, 2000)` where `b` is your batch size. We don't want to transform each element of `X` individually by doing `W*x` as above since this would be inefficient.
Instead we would like to transform all inputs at the same time. This can be done via `Y = X*W.T` where `W.T` is the transpose of `W`. You can work out that this essentially applies `W*x` to each row of `X` (i.e. each input). `Y` is then a `(b, 4800)` matrix containing *all* transformed inputs.

In Tensorflow, the weight matrix is simply saved in this transposed state, since it is usually the form that is needed anyway. Thus, we have a matrix with shape `(2000, 4800)` (the shape of `W.T`).

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! So, if I have a batch of `1` and the output shape is `(1, 4800)` and I need to multiple it with weight matrix `(2000, 4800)`, I can take the transpose of weight matrix and multiply, the output would be `(1, 2000)` and that would be correct? 

Also, I'm looking for a `4800`-vector as the output, in that scenario I'm thinking that I can add another layer which would have `4800` input(output from previous last layer) and `4800` output. My new weight matrix would then be `(4800, 4800)` should I then multiply by the transpose or original `4800x4800` matrix?

Comment: Continuing from above, these operations I'm doing are on an existing network for a test image. So, I take the test image, get the output of last layer and weight matrix and then perform matrix operations to transform that output further.

Comment: If the input/output dimensions are the same you don't need to transpose anything since your network will learn the semantics of the weight matrix on its own (assuming you are training your own weights). So if you have a layer with a (4800, 4800) matrix `W` you could 1) use `X*W`, or could 2) use `X*W.T` -- in the latter case the network would simply learn the values of `W` transposed compared to what it would learn in the first case. The only important thing is that the dimensions are correct to allow for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.